# Setting an Alarm

Tags: android-studio, alarmmanager

I have set an alarm and it works fine, but every time I reboot my phone the alarm starts.
I want that when the phone reboot the alarm still work and if the alarm should have started in the time the phone was off the alarm will start after the phone turned on.

```
 Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(Form.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Form.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        /* Set the alarm to start at 00:00 AM */
        Calendar Time = Calendar.getInstance();
        Time.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        Time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Minute);
        Time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Hour);

        /* Repeating on every day minutes interval */
        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, Time.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pIntent);
```

Manifest

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
```

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</intent-filter>
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hope, the value in your variables `Minute` and `Hour` refers to future time with respect to current time else the alarm will trigger immediately if its value is <= Current Time.